# How to eval Blade variable when pulling variable from database

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am using Laravel 5.7 I am having a variable stored in the database and would like to have it evaluated by Blade before rendering.

### Database

> Field: name, Value: {{ $organisername }}

I am pulling out this piece of data into a Blade template like this.

```
<h4>1. Registration</h4>
<br />
{{ $job->organisername }}
```

Chrome then displays **{{ $organisername }}** instead of evaluating **{{ $organisername }}**.

> ### 1. Registration
>
> {{ $organisername }}

If I type {{ $organisername }} into the Blade template, it gets evaluated to **John** when the page is rendered..

> ### 1. Registration
>
> John

I'm using TinyMCE to input {{ $organisername }} into the textarea, and it gets saved into a Database, if that helps.

Comment: Why don't you just let the code get sanitized on output only? This way you will not lose valuable data.

Answer (score 0):

If by evaluate you mean to do some consistency for your variable, know that this Blade echo statement "{{ }}" already does that with **htmlspecialchars**, like explained in the docs:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#displaying-data

Comment: Thanks but it's not what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

Blade templates are compiled down into PHP before they evaluate.  Essentially, blade compiles:

```
{{ $job->organisername }}
```

Into

```
<?php echo e($job->organisername); ?>
```

Once you understand this and how PHP evaluates variables, you should be able to understand why you can't set Blade constructs in the database and have them evaluated when it's printed.

It's basically the same as echoing a literal string:

```
<?php echo '{{ $organisiername }}'; ?>
```

You wouldn't want  Blade or PHP evaluating any expression they come across as they print, that would potentially be very insecure.

Comment: It's for a personal repository so i'm not worried about security at the moment.

Comment: That doesn't matter, it won't be possible because of php doesn't evaluate strings when they are printed.  It evaluates expressions when assigning, not printing.  Try it out:  `$variable = 123; $printed = '$variable'; echo $printed;`